# The mean value theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and its application to show that functions are independent of a variable

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I am currently reading through several multivariable calculus books to understand the proofs better (most of which go back to introduce functions in $\mathbb{R}$ for which the results are already evident). Ultimately I stumbled across:

> **Mean Value Theorem**: Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open.  
>  Let $x,y \in \Omega$ such that $[x,y] \subset \Omega$ then there $\exists \xi \in [x,y]$ such that $$ f(y)-f(x)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial(y-x)}(\xi)$$

I understand the proof of this theorem (it's mainly a clever trick to reduce it to a problem in $\mathbb{R}$ and the chain rule for curves) but then the Author (Pöschel) gives 2 comments:

1) Similar as in $\mathbb{R}$ if all the partial derivatives are equal to $0$ then $f$ is constant.

Nothing to say here, this is evidently true by the formula above. What bothers me is the 2nd comment:

> 2) Consider the case $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=0, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $f$ does not depend on $x$

When I first read that comment it was 'intuitively clear' to me. I thought that I should try to prove it and this is where I fail.

**My Approach**: I want to show that $f(x,y)=h(y)$ where $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and by obvious reasons I want to do so by applying the mean value theorem.

I often find it easier to just remind myself that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ rather than to write $x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2)$  but maybe in this situation it's necessarly.

I only know that $\partial_x f(x,y)=0, \ \forall(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ the only way I see is to establish this situation in the theorem is by letting $y=0$ and considering $f(-x)$ rather than $f(x)$ then I'd have $\exists \xi \in [x,0]$ such that $$f(0)-f(-x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi)=0 \implies f(0)=f(-x) $$

But the equation $f(0)=f(-x)$ doesn't help me at all to understand that comment. Is there something very obvious that I am missing out? Or do I mainly need to focus on  $\partial_yf(x,y)$ ?

Comment: For 2) define $h(y):=f(0,y)$ and prove that $f(x,y)\equiv h(y)$.

Comment: Another way to do this is to show that $f(x,y)-f(x+h,y)=0$ for all $x$ and for all $h$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Professor @ChristianBlatter, with your approach I obtain the statement $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial (x,0)}(\epsilon) \overset{?}{=} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\epsilon) $$
If I use the definition $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}(x,y)= \lim_{t \to 0} = \frac{f((x,y)+th)-f(x,y)}{t}$$ then I get for h$=(x,0)$ that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial(x,0)}(x,y) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f((x,y) + t(x,0))-f(x,y)}{t}= \lim_{t \to 0} = \frac{f(x+tx,y)-f(x,y)}{t} $$
I suppose they are both the same because they only add a small perturbation in the $x$ direction, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that there exist $x_0$, $x_1$, $y_0$ such that
$$f(x_0,y_0)\neq f(x_1,y_0)$$

Define $h_{y_0}(x)=f(x,y_0)$. Our hypothesis is that $h_{y_0}'\equiv 0$. But MVT tells us that there exists $\xi\in(x_0,x_1)$ (this is an interval, not a point!) such that
$$h_{y_0}'(\xi)=\frac{h_{y_0}(x_1)-h_{y_0}(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$$
and since $h_{y_0}'(\xi)=0$ we have that $h_{y_0}(x_1)=h_{y_0}(x_0)$, a contradiction.

We conclude that $h_{y_0}$ is comstant for every $y_0\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer to this question. I can follow your proof, more a question of curiosity here: Is it necessary to raise a contradiction as you did? When I start reading your proof from the third line (that is defining $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as you did) your proof just reads as fine to me.

Comment: I just find easier to understand. But what you say is correct, too.